# iphone: camera overlay, part of image preview inside overlay should be captured

Tags: iphone, camera

can anybody suggest me how can I achieve this

1) in camera mode I 'll add an overlay (this part is achievable)
2) only the image inside that overlay should be captured

please refer this pic

[image]

only the part of image in yellow section of sample image should be captured.
Please help me on this I am pretty new to this

Regards
Ankit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply capture the entire image, apply a mask to throw out what you don't want, and save/use the resulting image.

To apply a mask, have a look at http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html.

Comment: Akshay: I told you I am pretyy new to this can you please elaborate it means how to apply a mask and all

Comment: My main point was that you don't need the image already cut-out, but you can do that after capturing the image. Edited my answer.

Comment: See the comments at the link.